# What temperature would you heat frozen lasagna in the oven at?

Tags: reheating, lasagna

We froze some leftover homemade lasagna and instead of reheating in the microwave we would like to use the oven. What is a good temperature and time for reheating?

Comment: Exact time is going to depend on the type of container and the shape/size of the lasagna (eg, if it's 2" thick in a thin metal pan vs. 4" thick in stoneware).

Comment: Next time start it in the microwave, full power until you get some warming at the edges, then half power a bit more. Meanwhile the oven is warming... cover in foil and pop it in until the center hits a good temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

350F is the magic temp. Just about every casserole cooks at 350, and you cook it until it starts being bubbly which will probably between 30 minutes and an hour (in this case, you should check to make sure it's hot in the center as well, since you're starting from frozen). I'd cover it early, and then uncover it near the end so the top won't get dry.

Comment: Thanks, it took quite a while, over an hour at 350 plus a  microwave kicker at the end. :)

Comment: If you have a probe style thermometer look to get the internal temperature around 160˚F.